# Setting mail sender through mail.From in VBA

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Hi there I cannot run the following code for creating a mail object with VBA in outlook. What does not work is the setting of the sender mail address.

```
Dim outobj As Object

Set outobj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set mail = outobj.CreateItem(0)

    mail.From = "goofy@gmail.com"
    mail.To = "goofy@gmail.com"
    mail.Bcc = "goofy@gmail.com"
    mail.Subject = "Mail"
```

The code mail.From does not work and a run time error ('438') saying that the property or method is not supported by the object... why that happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct wording is

```
mail.SentOnBehalfOfName ="..."
```

Now the code works properly.